# Deploying SAR archives to WildFly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have to migrate an application that currently uses JBoss AS 6.1 to WildFly 8.2. This application uses something like 5 SAR files.

1. Could someone tell me what SAR files do?
2. Could they be deployed in WildFly?
3. Are there any alternatives to using SAR files in WildFly?

Answer (score -2):

**Compressed archive (SAR)**

SAR is a file extension for an archive file used with SAP business systems. SAR files contain compressed versions of delivered files and executables used by the SAP CRM. SAR files can be opened by the SAPCAR compression utility. SAPCAR is a command-line compression utility.

The prior version of SAPCAR was called CAR, and created CAR files. SAR files are the result of changes in the SAP CRM which required changes to the compression that was used, hence the introduction of SAPCAR.

How to solve your problem?
You can disable it only for your SAR deployment by defining it in jboss-**deployment-structure.xml** not for whole server.

Try disabling / removing weld subsystem, that will also resolve your issue.
But in all above solutions, you will loose CDI Support.

Let me know, if above solution is not suffice.

Comment: i am talking about SAR files wrt to JBoss.

Comment: It is related to JBoss Application Server.

Comment: The question is about Service ARchive files as described here: https://awakepower.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/how-to-create-sar-service-archive-file-for-jboss-with-maven/